# Pairing and connecting in iPhone app over Bluetooth/Blutooth LE

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I am starting to read up on the iOS5 Core Bluetooth Framework and I am writing an app that connects to a device from my iPhone or iPad 3.

Do I need to do the searching and pairing/connecting in my app, or is it presumed that the iPhone would pair/connect to the device and then I can use the available devices?

To possibly answer my own question, maybe I can do either?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm not sure cuz i did not try but hope this helps : [core bluetooth framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CoreBluetooth_Framework/CoreBluetooth_Framework.pdf)

and in this documentation it just retrieves the peripherals (means searching)and that means you just need to call that method to get the available peripherals around you..
and then of course you need to connect this peripheral with another method in the documentation.

also there is another method for the previously known peripherals for direct connection as i understand..

hope this helps to you..